# Animating to mouse/touch position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate a div to where I have triggered a `mousedown` event.  Kinda like a scroll bar does.  I want the div to follow the mouse if I continually hold the button down and move the mouse.  How do I do this?  The `mousedown` event I have thusfar simply adds the value of where I clicked to the top of the clicked element.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w20z2mew/3/)

```
$("#scroll").on("mousedown", function(ev){
    var y_pos = ev.pageY;
    $(this).animate({top: });
    console.log(y_pos);
})
```

Comment: have you tried mousemove event?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to show what the mousemove event does

Comment: Amazing, a thumbs down, no explanation why.  Not knowing how to do something is not a reason to give a thumbs down.  And don't say I'm being too broad, that it's a duplicate, or that it's unclear what I'm asking.

Comment: any reason why you got a thumbs down? u usually need to comment when giving a thumbs down. it could probably be because u might have not replied to the answers below.

Comment: I have no idea why people are giving thumbs down, but I'm not surprised when it comes to this community.  I haven't made comments on answers given or accepted any of them yet because I haven't been able to test the solutions yet.

Comment: hmm.. maybe you should try testing the answers then.

Answer (score 0):

A great suggestion by robert M [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15800223/4784297) to move a div with the mouse movements. I added a [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/lauraf/5ju5pjwf/2/) -

[This Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/lauraf/q2fpt03y/) takes your design into consideration. The css had to be changed to allow the function to work so maybe consider changing your css a little and then getting the max top position and max bottom position dynamically for the lowest and highest Y points.

HTML:

```
<div id="content1">    
    Suggested by <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/2242705/robert-m">Robert M</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:relative; /* make sure the div you want to move is relative*/
}
#content1 {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Robert's script

```
jQuery.fn.dragdrop = function (el) {
        this.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
            var relX = e.pageX - $(el).offset().left;
            var relY = e.pageY - $(el).offset().top;
            var maxX = $('body').width() - $(el).width() - 10;
            var maxY = $('body').height() - $(el).height() - 10;
            $(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
                var diffX = Math.min(maxX, Math.max(0, e.pageX - relX));
                var diffY = Math.min(maxY, Math.max(0, e.pageY - relY));
                $(el).css('left', diffX + 'px').css('top', diffY + 'px');
            });
        });
        $(window).bind('mouseup', function (e) {
            $(document).unbind('mousemove');
        });
        return this;
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        return $('div').dragdrop('div');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try replacing your script with this and see if you get the desired output.
I've quickly made this so I am not sure if it might be 100% correct but I think this will give you an idea as to how it is supposed to be written.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var initialPositionY = 0;
    var currentPositionY = 0;
    var move = false;

    $("#scroll").on("mousedown", function(ev){
        var y_pos = ev.pageY;
        initialPositionY = ev.pageY;
        move = true;
        console.log(move + ' -- ' + initialPositionY + ' -- ' + y_pos);
    });

    $("#scroll").on("mousemove", function(ev){
        if(move == true){
            var y_pos = ev.pageY;
            y_pos = ev.pageY - initialPositionY + currentPositionY;

            if(y_pos > 0)
                $(this).animate({top: y_pos}, 10);

            console.log(move + ' -- ' + initialPositionY + ' -- ' + y_pos);
        }
    });

    $("#scroll").on("mouseup", function(ev){
        var y_pos = ev.pageY;
        currentPositionY += ev.pageY - initialPositionY;
        move = false;

        console.log(move + ' -- ' + currentPositionY + ' -- ' + y_pos);
    });
});
```